# Where is the skin overlay option in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I made my Minecraft skin but I don't know where to find the overlay option. I heard people say it's in settings but when I looked in there, there was nothing for Minecraft skins. Can someone help me understand, or tell me if there is another way?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?